# LetterSpace without \usepackage{fontspec}

Tags: fontspec, letterspacing

I need to increase the LetterSpace of a piece of my text.

I know that it is possible with this code:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\NewDocumentCommand{\allcaps}{m}{%
  {\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=7.5}#1}%
}
```

But this code has to be run with LuaLaTeX (or maybe also XeLaTeX or others) but not with LaTeX.

Because I would like to keep running with LaTeX (otherwise the result will be different), in which other way I can modify the LetterSpace of a text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "LaTeX" means pdflatex you can use microtype:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
ABC \textls[500]{ABC}
\end{document}
```

[image]